# JSON character limit

Tags: json, eval

I have used Prototype and Mozilla evalJSON and with a nested datum >=64 characters it inserts an ellipsis.  I know how preposterous this sounds, I have traced it from the server to the client and it is perfect before call.  I have looked for any hard limits and found none.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sharing your code is a must. Without, impossible to help.

Comment: Actually there is nothing to share other than the observation.  If I use Prototype's #evalJSON or Mozillia's JSON.parse for datum less than 64 characters works perfectly, greater then 64 it is elided; actually cuts the string and inserts three dots.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you're doing, how can we be sure we're reproducing your problem? Adding the code to the question allows others to reproduce what you're seeing and provide an analysis.

Comment: The console is probably displaying the value in elided form. How are you viewing the value?

Comment: It is not the console, I am seeing the elided value in the function call.  It happens even if I do not have firebug active.  I am sure other have had contraindicating experience with datum >64 mine is consistent in this failure.